# Update or Insert into table, using rows from same table

Tags: merge, oracle11g

Let's say I have a table named FRUITS like this:

| ID | PRODUCT | ACTIVE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 1 |
| 1 | orange | 1 |
| 2 | orange | 0 |

(**ID = 1 has two PRODUCTS, and both have ACTIVE = 1**).

Now I want output in same table like this:

| ID | PRODUCT | ACTIVE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 1 |
| 1 | orange | 1 |
| 2 | orange | **1** |
| **2** | **apple** | **1** |

**So what I need is to Insert or Update values in a table, based on a condition for PRODUCT and ID from same table.**

**Or in another words - I want to copy all columns from existing ID into rows of given ID with same PRODUCT (UPDATE) or INSERT if rows with same PRODUCT doesn't exist under given ID.**

Is there a way that this could be done with a single statement, like **MERGE**?

I tried with this MERGE statement, but It doesn't work:

```
MERGE INTO fruits d
        USING (SELECT id, 
                      product, 
                      active
                FROM fruits
                WHERE id = :old_id_in) s
        ON (d.id = :new_id_in AND d.product = s.product)
      WHEN MATCHED THEN           
        UPDATE SET d.product = s.product,
                            d.active = s.active
        WHERE d.id = :new_id_in     
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT (d.id, d.product, d.active)
           VALUES(:new_id_in, s.product, s.active);
```

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
MERGE INTO fruits dst
USING (
  SELECT :new_id_in AS new_id,
         product,
         active
  FROM   fruits
  WHERE  id = :old_id_in
) src
ON (dst.id = src.new_id AND dst.product = src.product)
WHEN MATCHED THEN           
  UPDATE
  SET active = src.active
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (id, product, active)
  VALUES(src.new_id, src.product, src.active);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE fruits (ID, PRODUCT, ACTIVE) AS
SELECT 1, 'apple',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'orange', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'orange', 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the `MERGE` the table contains:

```sql
SELECT * FROM fruits ORDER BY id, product
```

| ID | PRODUCT | ACTIVE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 1 |
| 1 | orange | 1 |
| 2 | apple | 1 |
| 2 | orange | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EnVreRpK)

Comment: @Lucy82 Sorry, confused by the question. Updated to what I think you want.

Comment: @MTO, exactly like that, thanks for that !!! I was allready thinking that MERGE isn't possible for this :)